# Getting all the anchor tags of a web page

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Given a web URL, I want to detect all the links in a **WEBSITE**, identify the internal links and list them.

What I have is this:

```
            WebClient webClient = null;
            webClient = new WebClient();

            string strUrl = "http://www.anysite.com";
            string completeHTMLCode = "";

            try
            {
                completeHTMLCode = webClient.DownloadString(strUrl);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {                    
            }
```

Using this I can read the contents of the page....but the only idea I have in my mind is parsing this string....searching for `<a` then `href` then the value between the double quotes.

Is this the only way out? Or there lies some other better solution(s)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack). Here's a link to a [blog post](http://runtingsproper.blogspot.com/2009/11/easily-extracting-links-from-snippet-of.html) to get you started. Do not use Regex.

Answer (score 2):

using `HtmlAgilityPack`

```
 completeHTMLCode = 
   webClient.DownloadString(strUrl);

 doc.Load(completeHTMLCode);
 foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//a[@a"])
 {
   //
 }
```